# Is there an example for the Greenleaf theorem?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, model-theory, p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

I'm looking for an example for the Greenleaf theorem:

> Let $f_1(x)=\dots=f_n(x)=0$ be polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. For all except finitely many primes $p$, all solutions in $\mathbb{F}^n _p$ can be lifted to solutions in $\mathbb{Z}^n_p$.

I can't understand how a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ can have a solution in $\mathbb{F}^n _p$.

Comment: What is the greenleaf theorem? What does it mean to lift a solution in $F_p^n$ to a solution in $Z^n_p$?

Comment: Presumably you consider the solutions to the polynomials with coefficients reduced mod $p$. In other words, there is a map $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ given by reducing the coefficients mod $p$.

Comment: While this question is relevant to the model theory of values fields and the Ax-Kochen theorem, the question itself has nothing to do with model theory.

Comment: I added some more relevant tags and cleaned up the post.